# Writing contents to a Java file without format modification

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

Which method can I use to write some output to a file without modifying the format of it?

The following is the contents (as generated by the System.out.println() method) I would like to write:

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

a  b   <-- classified as
47  2 |  a = 1
28  0 |  b = 0
```

When I use the write method on a BufferedWriter object, the entire text gets printed as one line. The output was generated by the weka tool's eval.toMatrixString() method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`BufferedWriter#newLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) to add a new line separator to the end of the line

**Updated**

If it's not possible for generate the output manually, you may need to ensure that the `toMatrixString` is using appropriate line separators...

Take a look at the `System.getProperty("line.separator")` value

Comment: Thanks for getting back! Quick question though: How could I use the newLine() method? The output is generated by the eval.toMatrixString(). I get that format when I use System.out.println(eval.toMatrixString()); There is no loop. All of it happens in one iteration. Even if I try to split the string into tokens, I can't think of a valid delimiter for that format.

Comment: Then you have a problem.  The `toMatrixString` needs to be providing appropriate line separators for your platform.  Can you post the `toMatrixString` method?

Comment: The source is: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.java#Evaluation.toMatrixString%28java.lang.String . The method is from line 2517 to 2573. Please let me know if you would like me to paste that method as a reply. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Just a moment! Weka lets me write the output to a file directly. I think I am just complicating things unnecessarily. I will look into it and get back! Thanks a lot again!